# Extract area of polygons from ggvoronoi

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to extract the areas each observation from ggvoronoi such that I get a new dataframe with the first column being the observation and the next column being the area of the polygon.

```
library(ggvoronoi)
set.seed(45056)
x <- sample(1:200,100)
y <- sample(1:200,100)

ggplot(points,aes(x,y)) +
stat_voronoi(geom=“path”) +
geom_point()
```

Answer (score 1):

First convert your data to a sf object:

```
library(sf) 
set.seed(45056)
x <- sample(1:200,100)
y <- sample(1:200,100)
points <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)   
points_sf <- st_as_sf(points, coords = c("x", "y"))
```

Then you can use the following functions to calculate the area of each polygon:

```
v <- points_sf %>% 
  st_union() %>%
  st_voronoi() %>%
  st_collection_extract() %>%
  st_area()
```

Combine with the original data:

```
cbind(x, y, v)
```

Comment: How can I join it to the original data? or is it just in its order? many thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

[ggvoronoi](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deldir/index.html) uses the [deldir](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deldir/index.html) library to compute Voronoi tessellation. deldir returns a list of objects, which has a summary data frame for the points triangulated and the areas you are looking for.

You could run deldir on the same input to get the areas - `dir.area` column in the summary. For example:

```
?deldir

x = c(0, 1)
y = c(0, 1

d = deldir(x, y)

> d$summary
  x y n.tri del.area del.wts n.tside nbpt dir.area dir.wts
1 0 0     0        0     NaN       1    2     0.72     0.5
2 1 1     0        0     NaN       1    2     0.72     0.5
```

Comment: Hi kib. I am not familiar with deldir or ggvoronoi.. Would you like to say more about how which columns in d$summary would give what the OP wants?